# Avoid premature advocation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When reading answers, the first thing a user sees is the number of upvotes.

This influences the user before the user reads the answer - a lot of upvotes predisposes the user to thinking the answer is a good answer and vice versa.

What if the upvotes were aligned to the bottom of the answer instead of the top?

```
vertical-align: bottom
```

Comment: *“a lot of upvotes predisposes the user to thinking the answer is a good answer”* That’s what upvotes are for – pointing out good answers.

Comment: And vice versa, downvotes indicate: don't waste your time on this one.

Comment: Yep, lets hide our **strongest quality signal** from users.

Answer (score 3):

> When reading answers, the first thing a user sees is the number of upvotes

This is exactly how the site is intended to work.  Presumably, you don't downvote an answer that makes sense/works for the situation in question, and you don't upvote one that **doesn't** work in the situation in question.  Votes are used to indicate that the answer is a good answer.  Much like ratings on eBay.  If you took those away, how would you know who to deal with and who to avoid?